# jsp <input> value not being displayed with class form-control

Tags: javascript, html, class, form-control

I am generating `HTML` code using `jsp` and the `html` output looks like this:-

`<input type="text" style="font-weight:bold; background-color: orange; color: blue;" name="req_hallname" class="form-control" title="Conference Hall Requested" value="CIG-VC">`

wherein the `value=""` is filled with `CIG-VC` from the `jsp code`.

This value of `CIG-VC` is **NOT** visible when I am using `class="form-control"`. If I delete the `class="form-control"` definition, the input field **IS** visible with value but the formatting gets spoilt.

Here is the image of both situations

[image]

Please advise how to overcome this.

Comment: Well that is very odd and shouldn't happen. Don't you have a css rule setting both background and color to white?

Comment: I know.  I have added an image showing both situations.

Comment: This might have something to do with the component's width. `form-control` makes the item be 100% width. If the parent container has `width: auto` or some small size, it'll not work properly.

Comment: I am already on it. There seems to be some issue on how the JSP compiles the html part of it and how it adds the `value=""` from the java variable. The [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94ebywo0/10/) is working fine. So I tried making the `width:200%`, then I am seeing some characters and with 400% I can see about 6 characters. But this is not generic code. So I need to look for something else.

Comment: Try changing it to `width: auto;`

Comment: I tried that first, but it didn't work. So i made hard code of 400%.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use:

```
 <div class="form-group" >
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="conference">Conference Hall Requested 
   :
  </label>
     <div class="col-sm-8"> 
      <input id="conference" type="text" style="font-weight:bold; background-
         color:orange; color: blue;"  name="req_hallname" value="CIG-VC"/>
     </div>
 </div>
```